# Crop background image left and right

Tags: html, css

I am applying a background image to a `div`:

```css
div {
  background: white url("https://placekitten.com/1000/1000") no-repeat left top / 100% auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Some text ...<p>
</div>
```

I need to crop 50 pixels left and right of the background image.

But I still want to display it with a 100% width to fill the entire screen width.

How can I do this?

Comment: `background: white url("background.png") no-repeat top / calc(100% + 100px) auto;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add 100 pixel to the size of the image with "calc(100% + 100px)" and crop the image by positioning it -50px to the left.

```css
div {
  min-height: 200px;
  min-width: 200px;
  background: white url("https://placekitten.com/1000/1000") no-repeat -50px top / calc(100% + 100px) auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Some text ...<p>
</div>
```